# OnKeyUp,OnKeyDown and onKeyPress

Tags: javascript, forms, onkeypress

I try to use all here in this combination:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

 function CountLeft(field, count, max) 
 {
     if (field.value.length > max)
         field.value = field.value.substring(0, max);
     else
         count.value = max - field.value.length;
 }

</SCRIPT>
<input name="text" onKeyDown="CountLeft(this.form.text, this.form.left,50);"
                   onKeyUp="CountLeft(this.form.text,this.form.left,50);"  onKeyPress="return entsub(event)">


<input readonly type="text" name="left" size=3 maxlength=3 value="50">  
characters left
```

But the enter key to submit does not work here, can anyone tell me how I can fix that? 
Oh and, I am trying to make a counter here.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a form, so nothing can be submitted really.

Comment: there is an actual form, just not included in the code i provided here, didn't feel that was necessary.

Comment: try replacing "this.form.text" with 'this' only onKeyDown and onKeyUp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need all these keyhandlers. One *keydown handler* would be sufficient.

The here given function `keyhandler` stops updating the text input value after `max` is reached and submits the form if the key pressed was `enter`. You can find an example @ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/2hrt7/.

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="return keyhandler(this,event,50)"/>
```

now keyhandler looks like this:

```
function keyhandler(obj,e,max) {
    e = e || event;
    max = max || 50;
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        return document.forms[0].submit();
    }
    if (obj.value.length >= max && e.keyCode>46) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

By the way, you are aware of the [`maxlength`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/maxlength) attribute of a text input field?

Comment: on the example the backscape key did not work when reached the max amount. and yes i am aware of maxlength, but here i am trying to display a counter.

Comment: @gdscei See the revised function.

Comment: Thanks, but how could I combine this with the counter code? see my edited question for my code on it.

Comment: the js-fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/2hrt7/) now contains a way to show the counter.

Comment: Glad I could help. Added some arithmetic to the fidlle to support backspace/delete and other keys

Comment: The newest code you put in does not function, it goes minus with spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I needed that script too and the one given by Kooilnc didn't really work for me. I used this:

```
function keyhandler(obj,e,max){
e = e || event;
max = max || 140;
var keycode = e.keyCode
  , len     = 0
  , This    = keyhandler
  , currlen = obj.value.length;

if (!('countfld' in This)){
    This.countfld = document.getElementById('letter-count');
}

if (keycode === 13) {
    //return document.forms[0].submit();
    return true;
}
if (currlen >= max) {
    This.countfld.innerHTML = '0';
    return false;
}
This.countfld.innerHTML = (max - obj.value.length);
return true;
```

}

And in the HTML file I used this:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="return keyhandler(this,event,140)">
```

I hope it works for you! :D